# Is makePersistent of JDO PersistentManager not enough for creating child elements?

Tags: java, jdo

I have some code like this

```
class root extends DomainObject{
Collection childElements;
Collection childElements2;
.....
//define other child element collections


Collection getChildElements(){
 return childElements;
}
// define other childElements getter/setter
```

and my package.jdo defines the mapping that looks like this

```
      <class name="root" identity-type="datastore" detachable="true" persistence-capable-superclass="com.xxx.DomainObject">
        <inheritance strategy="new-table"/>
        <field name="childElements" persistence-modifier="persistent" default-fetch-group="true">
            <collection element-type="com.my.CustomClass" />
            <join/>
            <order column="idx"/>
            <extension vendor-name="jpox" key="cache-lazy-loading" value="false"/>
        </field>
```

And the custom class structure may look something like this

```
class CustomClass extends DomainObject{
String name;
Collection otherElements;
.....


String getName(){
return name;
}    
Collection getOtherElements(){
 return otherElements;
}
```

Now for creating an object of com.my.CustomClass the code looks like this

```
persistenceManager().currentTransaction().begin();
CustomClass customObj = new CustomClass();
customobj.setName("someName");
//set other values    
persistenceManager.makePeristent(customObj);//persist
SomeUtil.getRoot().getChildElements().add(customObj);//add to its owner
persistenceManager.currentTransaction().commit();
```

and the code for getRoot() in SomeUtil looks something like this

```
 Query q = persistenceManager.newQuery( root.class );
 Collection c = (Collection)q.execute();
  persistenceManager.retrieveAll( c );
   return (root)c.iterator().next();
```

What i am failing to understand is why do we need to add this new Custom object to the owner? `SomeUtil.getRoot().getChildElements().add(customObj);`
The removal code also looks similar i.e., First the object is removed from its owner's collection and then `deletePersistent` of persistenceManger is called.

MyQuestion is
do we really need to add this object to the parent explicitly? Isn't `makePeristent()` alone not enough?The reason why iam asking is i see some performance hit with this 'getRoot()' (even if the underlying objects are lazily loaded there is some performance hit when the volume of these collections is high).

In runtime we use a cached/detachable copy(say a deep cloned) of this 'root' object and any required element is retrieved from this 'root' only.If there any modifications done to the db then we invalidate this cache and reload this root and cache it again.

Is it safe to remove that code where the child element is being added or removed explicitly to/from the parent? Or Is it really required based on the mapping we have defined(and given the fact that we rely on cached(cloned) root to retrieve all child elements in runtime)? 
Note that we aren't using the same 'root' during runtime ( a deep user cloned) and during creation of the object.Just that we are relying on 'root' for fetching other elements during runtime.
kindly let me know if any body has dealt with this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and observed that if you add the child element with out the knowledge of the parent then you cannot retrieve that child element **using parent**.

```
persistenceManager().currentTransaction().begin();
CustomClass customObj = new CustomClass();
customobj.setName("someName");
//set other values    
persistenceManager.makePeristent(customObj);//persist
//comment this
//SomeUtil.getRoot().getChildElements().add(customObj);//add to its owner
persistenceManager.currentTransaction().commit();
```

Later when i loaded that  parent i found that the child element is not retrieved.

```
 Collection c = SomeUtil.getRoot().getChildElements()
 // Iterate over this collection and found that element is not present
```

As i said earlier we rely on this root object in runtime to retrieve any child element.
Even though querying the children directly works it is not an option for us.

Looks like we can only achieve this by adding that child to parent.
But we wanted to avoid this because retrieving parent(root) has some hit in performance(even when they are lazily loaded) as this root has many other children collection elements. In runtime we usually load this root once and cache the clean copy.

Answer (score 0):

JDO persistence by reachability is well defined in the JDO spec. The DataNucleus log tells you what is persisted and when. I'd strongly suggest reading of those two resources

Comment: My question is actually opposite.Isn't persistence by Reachability applicable only when i start persisting from parent?Just to put my question in simpler way, If i add child first is there a way to tell the parent to 'own' this? BTW we are using jpox 1.1

Comment: If you're using "jpox 1.1" then why tag this question as "datanucleus", and obviously jpox is not supported from 2007 so you're on your own.

Comment: Thats because stackoverflow doesn't allow newbies to create new tag (surprising that jpox tag does not exist) Anyways i think the question is applicable to datanucleus as well